# git: How to recover uncommited changes from staged deleted file?

Tags: git

I did with git:

```
git commit fileA
```

Then I edited `fileA`

Then I accidentally performed

```
git rm fileA
```

Is there a way to recover the `fileA` from after performing the `git rm`?  `git reset` and `git checkout` will discard my edits and get the `fileA` from after the commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to recover a file after you perform a `git rm`.

As you stated performing

```
git reset HEAD
```

or

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

will revert back to the previous set of the file.